# push notification is not working foreground app in android ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor-plugin

I have added this to capacitor.config.json file

```
"PushNotifications": {
      "presentationOptions": [
       "badge", "sound", "alert"
      ]
    }
```

but it not work please help me

Comment: Can you add more information ..

Comment: Send payload for sending push notification